# Row Reduce Augmented Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image: row]

I am having issues actually row reducing it.

What I initially get for the augmented matrix is:

\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc|c}  
  0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 2\\
  2 & -2 & 4 & -1 & 10\\
  1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 2\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 9
 \end{array}\end{pmatrix}

But I am unsure how to actually use the elementary operations to solve this. It's a practice problem in my textbook and I want to know how to do this because I have an upcoming test. I hope someone can help me out here, really would appreciate any help.

Thanks everyone, just need help with this.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that we may use only three types of row operations:

- Swap two rows;
- Multiply a row by a non-zero constant; and
- Add a multiple of one row to another row.

Provided we stick to these operations, we preserve the set of solutions to the system of linear equations.

Here's my selection of row operations in this instance.  The exact choice of which row operation to apply when is often personal preference (and partly based on experience as to what works).

\begin{align*}
& \left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & -2 & 4 & -1 & 10 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 & 
0 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 9 \\ \end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{R_1 \leftrightarrow R_3} & \left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 2 & -2 & 4 & -1 & 10 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 & 
1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 9 \\ \end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{R_2 \gets R_2-2R_1} & \left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & -1 & 6 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 & 
1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 9 \\ \end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{R_4 \gets R_4-R_1} & \left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & -1 & 6 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 & 
1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 7 \\ \end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{R_2 \leftrightarrow R_4} & \left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 7 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 
2 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & -1 & 6 \\ \end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{R_3 \gets R_3-R_2} & \left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 7 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 
-5 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & -1 & 6 \\ \end{array}\right] \\
\xrightarrow{R_4 \gets R_4+R_3} & \left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 7 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 
-5 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
which is in [row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).  If a solution exists, the last row would imply $0=1$, which is a contradiction.  Hence the system is inconsistent (i.e., no solution exists).

Comment: You have made an error writing down the original matrix, the first row should be $(0\enspace 1\enspace -2 \enspace 1| 2)$, if you fix this, then it actually yields an inconsistent system (the rest of your computations seem to be good), so the set of equations has no solution.

Comment: Yes @Rebecca can you please fix that? You wrote the original matrix first row incorrectly. I think it will change up the rest of your solution . Hope you can do that, and I can look over it once you fix the mistakes. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: @user41580 the rest of the computations don't change, I would recommend just changing the original matrix and then follow the rest of Rebecca's work, it will be a good exercise too!

Comment: Ah oops, sorry!  It's so easy to have bugs in these computations.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

0 1 -2 1 | 2

2 -2 4 -1 | 10

0 1 0 0 | 7

1 0 1 0 | 9

0 0 2 -1 | 5

2 0 4 -1 | 24

0 1 0 0 | 7

1 0 1 0 | 9

0 0 2 -1 | 5

0 0 2 -1 | 6

0 1 0 0 | 7

1 0 1 0 | 9

Therfore, inconsistent. You can also continue all the way to reduced echelon form and have something like 0+0+0+0 = a, which cannot be true.

**Added:**

One more step

0 0 0 0 | 1

0 0 2 -1 | 6

0 1 0 0 | 7

1 0 1 0 | 9

Notice that 0+0+0+0 cannot equal 1. If you get something like this then the system is inconsistent.

Comment: What did you mean by 0+0+0+0 = a? Where is a?

Comment: Also I'm unsure what you did in the second step, can you please elaborate on that

Comment: to go from the first row to the second row add $2R_3+R_2$ to get a new row $2$ and add $-R_3+R_1$ to get a new row $1$, and then multiply $R_1$ by $(-1)$ to get the matrix they got in the second step.

Comment: @user41580 I added another step to explain what I meant by 0 = a. a is a number different from 0. Look at Curtis's response to see the operations I made. Note that in the middle step I used two operations.